# How to get the value form Materialize's Switches?

Tags: javascript, materialize

I'm using the [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) library and I'm trying to retrieve the value from the [switches component](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#switches), but it always returns `on` regardless of it being turned on or off.

Is there a way to determine if it's switched on or off, programatically?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have to use .checked
For example:
Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('mySwitch').checked
```

JQuery:

```
$('#mySwitch').prop('checked')
```

I hope that I help you.

Comment: Yes, silly me too :). And $('#mySwitch').prop('checked', true) as setter.